# Smooth transition between two edge loops

Tags: mesh, geometry

I've inherited some STL files for a device enclosure (meant to be 3D printed) that I need to alter. It contains several standoffs (posts for mounting circuit boards) that transition smoothly into the bottom and walls of the housing. Some of them are along a flat surface, which is easy, but other are tucked into the corner, like this one:

[image: Origin standoff]

The trouble is, I need to move these beautifully modeled standoffs a few millimeters here and there. The one pictured above needs to go further into the corner shown behind it in both X and Y.

I've tried deleting the transition faces (selected in the image) and using the "Bridge Edge Loops" tool with mixed success. I end up with a somewhat craggy surface with a radial faceting or stepping, as seen on the right side of the transition here (my best recreation attempt so far):

[image: Craggy transition]

This isn't going to print as well as I'd like, and the odd geometry may actually make this transition weaker (some standoffs are tall). More importantly, doing it this way limits me to using the existing outer loops of the transitions.

So, how do I achieve the transition shown in the first image? I'm open to deleting the standoffs, simplifying wall and corner geometry, and starting more or less from scratch.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't move the whole transition piece along with the standoff?

Comment: I need to move this particular standoff into that corner behind it, so the geometry of the corner and the back wall will become involved. Most of the other standoffs can be moved wholesale as you suggest, though.